# Vue not updating computed unless forced to

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have to add extra rows forcing Vue to recompute computed prop, specifically:

```
var foo = this.groups;
this.groups = {};
this.groups = foo;
```

as can be seen in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8bqv29dg/. Without these, `available_groups` is not updated.

Why is that and what is the clean way to have `available_groups` updating with `groups`?

Have tried adding `groups` to "deep-watched", but it did not help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vue doesn't track new elements added to an object:

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats

One solution is to use `Vue.set` or reassign the object, like the example below:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    groups: {1: {key: 1, label: 'Those guys'}},
  },

  computed: {
    available_groups: function() {
        return [{value: 0, label: 'Anyone'}].concat(Object.values(this.groups)); 
        },
    },
  methods: {
    add_group: function(key, name) {
        Vue.set(this.groups, key, {key: key, name: name})
    },
  }
})
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `$set` to add new property for data object:

```
   methods: {
    add_group: function(key, name) {
      this.$set(this.groups, key, {key, name});
    },
  }
```

[Here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) described vue reactivity